# Woocommerce customer list on a page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I using WordPress and Woocommerce and I wish to display a list of the users with their details on a single page. 
With this I get customers name, email, nickname, url:

```
 <?php $blogusers = get_users( 'orderby=nicename&role=dealer' );
// Array of WP_User objects.
echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
    echo '<li> <span>' . esc_html( $user->first_name ) .'</span> <span>' . esc_html( $user->last_name ) .'</span> <span>' . esc_html( $user->nickname ) .'</span> <span>'  . esc_html( $user->user_url ) .'</span> <span>'. esc_html( $user->user_email ) .'</span>'.'</li>';
}
echo '<ul>'; ?>
```

But how to get address, city, country, state etc. from "Customer Billing Address" details?

Any help appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woocommerce saves customers' data as usermeta. To access that you can use simple get meta syntax of WordPress e.g.

```
$billing_code = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'billing_postcode', true );
```

You can do the same for all other user meta values you need. Other than above meta field, you can pull other fields with meta keys using e.g. billing_address_1 , billing_address_2 , billing_city etc in place of billing_postcode using php code like in above example.

Comment: Thanks for a tip. I got it. Working ok.

Comment: Great! Good luck @rickybrce

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full code if someone need it:

```
$blogusers = get_users( 'orderby=nicename&role=dealer' );
// Array of WP_User objects.
echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $blogusers as $user) {
    echo '<li>
    <span>' . esc_html( $user->first_name ) .'</span> 
    <span>' . esc_html( $user->last_name ) .'</span> 
    <span>' . get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'billing_address_1', true ) .'</span>  
    <span>' . get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'billing_postcode', true ) .'</span> 
    <span>' . get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'billing_city', true ) .'</span>  
    <span>' . get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'billing_phone', true ) .'</span>  
    <span>'  . esc_html( $user->user_url ) .'</span> 
    </li>';
}
echo '<ul>'; 

?>
```

This will display users first and last name, address, postcode, city, phone and url. Need some css styling of course.

Comment: I created a page and added this code but it does not seem to work for me. Could you please tell me which page should I add this code to?

Comment: @rickybrce kindly let us know where to add this code!

Comment: Create a custom page template and add that code in it.